# I'm having trouble with the has_scope gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the has_scope gem and trying to find columns that contain nil/not nil info. It is not working.

I have two scopes in my model:

```
 scope :empty -> where(name: nil)
 scope :present -> where.not( title: nil)
```

in my controller:

```
    has_scope :empty
    has_scope :present

    def index
      clients = apply_scopes(Clients).all
    end
```

On the command line:

curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/clients?empty

Answer (score 0):

Forget the gem and just use the scopes directly (as nature intended!)

```
empty_name_clients = Client.empty

clients_with_names = Client.present
```

Also, I don't suggest you use the word 'present'  or 'empty' as scope names as those words are reserved by ActiveRecord and Ruby collections such as

`Client.last.appointements.empty?`  and `Client.last.present?`